# IOS UIView contains UIWebview with stale data - caching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I currently have an app that has been published to the app store.  I just notice there is a bug in one section of the app.  This app requires a user login via POST method.  Here is my scenario.

Login with userA.  Once logged in there is another viewController being called modally.  In this viewController on viewDidLoad there are 3 webviews.  This is where I call my loadRequest to retrieve the data from my webserver and display the results in the webviews.

Up to this point all of this is working just fine.

UserA logs out and then I log in userB.  When userB loads the webviews, userA data is being displayed instead of userB's data.

This is what I have done so far to try to fix the caching issue.
1) NSURLMutableRequest - set cache policy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

2) appended a random number to my post data to make every call unique to some degree
3) Modified my Apache2 config to include:

SetEnvIf Request_Method "POST" IS_POST
    Header add Pragma "no-cache" env=IS_POST

4) In my viewWillDisappear method I added the following:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
self.view = nil;
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

I also set to nil the 3 webviews which had zero results.

What am I missing here?  If I stop the app and restart it I see the correct data.  Also I am logging to the console my URL's being requested and they are in fact sending the correct
data.  The first webview is still being loaded instead of the current webviews data.  At this point I'm at a loss.  I hope someone can point me in the right direction.  Also this project is using ARC.

As always thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When userB is loading, in WebViewDidFinishLoading method try to reload webview.

```
if(userB){
  [webView Reload];
}
```

Reload will clear all previous cache.

Comment: Don't think that is going to be the right solution because this app has several hundred members at the moment and no telling how many multiple logins on the same device will be occurring.  Not to mention the reload being called on WebViewDidFinishLoading looks like infinite loop of reloads going on...